# How do I change a property value of an object within an Array? #swift

Tags: arrays, swift

```
@State private var myBoxArray = Array<Box>()
@State private var amountEligibleForSelection:Int = 0

struct Item: Hashable {
    var isCool:Bool? = nil
    init(_ isCool:Bool){
        self.isCool = isCool
    }
}

struct Box: Hashable {
    var boxNumber:Int? = nil
    var contents:Item? = nil
    var isSelected:Bool = false
    var revealBoxContents:Bool = false
    init(_ contents:Item, _ boxNumber:Int) {
        self.contents = contents
        self.boxNumber = boxNumber
    }
}


func SetupTheBoxs(_ howManyItems:Int) -> Array<Box> {
    var preparedBoxs = Array<Box>()
    var boxCounter = 0
    
    if boxCounter > howManyItems {
        preparedBoxs.append(Box(Item(false), boxCounter-1))
    }
    print(preparedBoxs)
    return preparedBoxs
}

myBoxArray = SetupTheBoxs(3)
```

```
func SelectAllBoxes(){
    for box in myBoxArray{
        if box.isSelected == false && box.contents!.isCool == false {
         box.isSelected = true
```

*Error: Cannot assign to property: 'Box' is a 'let' constant*

```
        }
    }
}
```

The state of the properties within myBoxArray triggers UIViews in my app, so I need these values to change and trigger. Why can't I change the property value?

Things I've tried:

1. Using a binding variable for myBoxArray (FAIL)
2. Added a mutating function to the Box struct to flip the 'isSelected':bool (FAIL)
3. Setting the function logic as a button action (FAIL)

Someone please help me. #crying

Comment: Unrelated but **never** declare struct members as optional which are initialized with non-optional values.

Answer (score 1):

You have to mutate the property that is marked with `@State` wrapper and not the separate instance of `Box` within your view. Try something like.

```
func SelectAllBoxes(){
    for index in 0..<myBoxArray.count{
          if myBoxArray[index].isSelected == false && myBoxArray[index].contents!.isCool == false {
            myBoxArray[index].isSelected = true
          }
      }
  }
```

Comment: when I try this, I get Fatal error "index out of range"

Comment: WAIT!!! `myBoxArray.count - 1` did the trick